# Keep getting No X509TrustManager implementation available error when trying to connect to web socket server

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, x509certificate, java-security

I have the following code for connecting to a web socket server in my java application using secure websockets.

```
private boolean openConnection(boolean tried) {
    String sslFile = 
        ConfigMgr.getValue(Constants.SSL_CFG_NAME, "sslfile"); 
    String sslPassword = 
        ConfigMgr.getValue(Constants.SSL_CFG_NAME, "sslpassword"); 
    try {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",
                //sslFile);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", sslPassword);
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (!tried) {
            logger.error("unable to get certificates", e);
        }
        return false;
    }
    try {
        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider
                .getWebSocketContainer();
        container.connectToServer(this, new URI(websocketServer));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // only log error trying to connection to web application first
        // time
        if (!tried) {
            logger.error("error while trying to connect daemon to websocket"
                    + " server", e);
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I can see from my print statements

```
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", sslPassword);
```

and

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));
```

That the correct password and certificate (a `.cer` in this case) with the contents

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

are being set correctly.

However when I run my code the following error gets printed when `container.connectToServer(this, new URI(websocketServer));` is ran

```
    javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection failed
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:434) ~[tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:184) ~[tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.68]
        at 
cored.web.CoreWebSocket.openConnection(CoreWebSocket.java:278) [cored.jar:3.0.10.160712122615]
        at cored.web.CoreWebSocket.establishConnection(CoreWebSocket.java:1150) [cored.jar:3.0.10.160712122615]
        at 
cored.web.CoreWebSocket.access$100(CoreWebSocket.java:85) [cored.jar:3.0.10.160712122615]
        at 
cored.web.CoreWebSocket$2.execute(CoreWebSocket.java:138) [cored.jar:3.0.10.160712122615]
        at utils.AThread.run(AThread.java:51) 
[utils.jar:3.0.10.160712122615]
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$WrapperFuture.get(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:511) ~[tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:379) ~[tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.68]
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$WebSocketSslHandshakeThread.run(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:371) ~[tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.68]
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$WebSocketSslHandshakeThread.run(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:397) ~[tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.68]
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
        at sun.security.ssl.DummyX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$WebSocketSslHandshakeThread.run(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:397) ~[tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.68]
```

I know the `.cer` file I am using is not corrupt since it is also being used on a tomcat webserver and has no problem.

What may be causing this `No X509TrustManager implementation available` error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`.cer` file is not a valid type for your truststore. You can use the system variable `javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType` to set the type. By default is set to `JKS`, you can also use PKCS12 for example.

You have to create a JKS file and include the .cer file. Configure also the password for the trusttore

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path/to/truststore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", truststorepassword);
```

To import a .cer file into a JKS use

```
keytool -importcert -file certificate.cer -keystore keystore.jks -alias "Alias"
```

Comment: so if i set the trust store with the system variable to a `.cer` kind I should be fine? We have to use a `.cer` and can't find a way around it with concerns of security.

Comment: You can not use the `.cer` file itself because is not a KeyStore file type accepted by JDK. You have to include the content of the `.cer`  into a JKS file. The security level is the same, it is just a format conversion issue. I have set in the answer how to import a .cer

Comment: thanks very much! took me about three days till i had to give up and come here, isn't security fun?

Comment: how to give that truststore path. my file is in resorces folder of java maven project

Comment: @SumanthVarada, it is a different question. Try posting the details in a new thread

Comment: Thank you so very much. I had generated the SSL cert to secure my Vault server (configured in Production Mode) using the openssl command:

`openssl req -out vault-tls.crt -new -keyout vault-tls.key -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -x509 -subj "/O=HashiCorp/CN=Vault" -days 3650 -extensions v3_req`

Then I generated the JKS version of the vault-tls.crt file, set the system properties for the trust store, and boom - my SpringBoot microservice, which is integrated with Secured Vault, started working..

`keytool -importcert -file vault-tls.crt -keystore vault-tls-keystore.jks -alias "Alias"`